# How to process TAL expressions in html when the html is returned as a variable?

Tags: plone

How can I get tal expressions declared inside context/get_html to be also processed by the tal interpreter? Is there a utility I can wrap around my get_html function declared in my browserview? I'm running Plone 5.

**Example:**

context/get_html will return:

```
<div tal:content="context/Title"></div>
```

If the html returned from context/get_html has tal expressions within it as shown above, they are not processed when the following is called:

```
<div id="content" tal:content="structure context/get_html"></div>
```

Results in this output:

```
<div id="content"><div tal:content="context/Title"></div></div>
```

When the desired output is:

```
<div id="content"><div>My Title</div></div>
```

Thanks for helping or taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal doesn't work that way. Everything needs to be in the template in order for it to be processed.

If you're using chameleon(which you are if you're on Plone 5 and can if you're on Plone 4 with a few addons), you can do this in your view code:

```
from chameleon import PageTemplate
template = PageTemplate("<div tal:content="context/Title"></div>")
template(context=context)
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use metal macro for this to happen!

For example get_html is a page template containing:

```
<metal:friendlyname define-macro="my-macro">
  <div id="content"><div tal:content="context/Title"></div></div>
</metal:friendlyname>
```

and use_macro is another template containing:

```
<metal:anothername use-macro="context/get_html/macros/my-macro" />
```

I you visit /your/context/use_macro the rendered output is exactly:

```
<div id="content"><div>Your Title ;)</div></div>
```

Check this out for reference:

- http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/ZPT.html#macros

Comment: The problem is the get_html is a variable which can change and is not a static template.  Macros require I hardcode the format.

Comment: You may want get_html to return the macro itself! Check this out: https://github.com/PloneGov-IT/rg.prenotazioni/blob/d61201661dea4d5186385ea26e541126110e3665/rg/prenotazioni/browser/week.py#L81

Comment: I've tested it and that still won't work.   The "manager_day_period" uses a macro which is a defined .pt file (hardcoded html).  I am not defining a .pt file in a product.  The get_html generates a dynamic .pt file.  Users can then edit the .pt template through-the-web.